# Symfony 4 how to use database test

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, symfony4

I have created a test for this function:

```
public function userRegistrationDatabase(String $email, String $keyRockId): object
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager("gui");
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUserName($email);
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $userRole = ['ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN'];
    $user->addRole(implode(",",$userRole));
    $user->setKeyrockId($keyRockId);
    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $user;
}
```

I have also created an sqlite db only for test purpose. The question is: during the test how can I switch db to be used?  This is the test:

```
public function testUserRegistrationDatabase()
{
    $userManager = self::$kernel->getContainer()
        ->get('test.'. UserManagement::class);
    $mail = 'notexistinguser@mail.com';
    $keyRockId = '45091fd63a1';

    $user = $userManager->userRegistrationDatabase($mail,$keyRockId);

}
```

the db I would like to use is :

```
self::$kernel->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager('test_gui');
```

So basically the function use `getManager("gui")` but in test I would like to use `getManager("test_gui")`.

Comment: If I well understand for tests you usually should use a different environments ('test') with a different configuration, service ... file (.yaml or .xml for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `getManager("test_gui")` you'll need to define a database connection with that name. In Symfony 3 such a configuration might look like this:

`../app/config.yml` (see [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)):

```
...
     doctrine
        connections:
            ...
            test_gui:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                path:     %kernel.root_dir%/cache/test/test.sqlite
```

There is a similar configuration in Symfony 4 (see [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)):

`../config/packages/doctrine.yaml`:

```
...
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            test_gui:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_TEST_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
```

where `DATABASE_TEST_URL` might be `"sqlite:///%kernel.root_dir%/cache/test/test.sqlite"`